# How can one restrict Windows shared folders access to specific applications?

Tags: windows, permissions

There are few shared folders in my company that are accessed by applications from different branches across the country for different transactions. Hence they are kept "open". During a recent PT exercise, this was reported as a finding. Though no write access is given, I understand that this is a security risk. The application owners claim that securing the shared folders would disrupt the normal running of the applications. I was wondering if there can be a secure set up so that only the designated applications can access these shares?

Comment: bAdb bOy there is really insufficient information to answer your question. As StackzOfZtuff notes, you could run the applications under a service account, but that will depend a bit on the architecture of the application. It would help if you added the following information: 1) are the applications web based, client/server or simple clients running on distributed machines. 2) are they locally developed applications that can be altered if necessary and 3) do they read write or just read?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to run the applications with application specific user accounts and then restrict access to only them.